# Logstash json filter not adding fields to the root of the event [EDITED]

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

When I use the json filter on a message, it magically disappears - never reaches elasticsearch. When I remove the filter, everything works fine.

Sample `_source` -

```
{"message":"{\"id\":\"5563017afd801c1618603a7b\",\"date\":\"2015-05-23T15:30:00.000Z\",\"count\":485}","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2015-05-25T11:07:49.913Z","type":"app","env":"production","host":"production-server","tags":["event"]}
```

I use a node app, [`node-lumberjack-protocol`](https://github.com/benbria/node-lumberjack-protocol) to send the messages.

This is what my filter looks like

```
json {
    source => "message"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

When I give a `target` to the `json` filter, the message is parsed and added to the target field. But I don't what that. I want the fields of the JSON to be added to the root of the event. Reading the [documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/json#target) for the json filter, I figured that will happen if I omit the `target`, unfortunately it seems it isn't so.

> Define the target field for placing the parsed data. If this setting is omitted, the JSON data will be stored at the root (top level) of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use input `codec` for adding the json message to the root.

For example,

```
input {
        stdin{
                codec => json
        }
}

output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Input:

```
{"id":"5563017afd801c1618603a7b","date":"2015-05-23T15:30:00.000Z","count":485}
```

Output:

```
{
        "id" => "5563017afd801c1618603a7b",
      "date" => "2015-05-23T15:30:00.000Z",
     "count" => 485,
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2015-05-27T03:45:33.094Z",
      "host" => "BEN_LIM"
}
```